# Generating Statistics With Polymorphic Data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to generate the statistics based on a polymorphic relationship. Each database which it can relate to has an identifier column, so I would like to ideally group the data by `identifier` (once I have the rest working).

I believe you can't use the `with` function on a polymorphic relationship, but I have attached my code because I think it illustrates what I'm trying to do quite well.

OrderItem MorphTo function

```
public function item()
{
    return $this->morphTo('item');
}
```

Statistics generator

```
public function groupOrderCountByType()
{       
    return OrderItem::with(['item' => function($query){
        $query->select(DB::raw('`identifier` AS `application_type`'));
    }])->select(DB::Raw('COUNT(`id`) AS `total`'))
    ->with(['order' => function($query){
        $query->where('paid', true);
    }])
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$this->from, $this->to])
    ->get();
}
```